# Learning Html and a new on wordpress designing and developing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a web designer whom used to work only on Adobe softwores for designing without coding.

recently I started learning html and working on bootstrap. However, my boss she told me that I have to start viewing WP designs and how their trends are going so I step in the word press development later on.

my question is, is there a connection between bootstrap and WP in coding and so on?

Comment: Yes you can convert your bootstrap design to dynamic wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

On the front end you can use whatever JS/CSS framework you like. You can use bootstrap if you wish but there is no inherent advantage from the wordpress development POV for using bootstrap over other frameworks.